# How to check if context can still be used in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-safety

In my android app I have a async task, that downloads an image and saves it to external storage, then repeats until all images are downloaded. This can take a while, and I reference the context from the activity that called it, a couple times in the async per downloaded image.

During this process the user could have pressed back or something which ends the context.

How can I check if I can still use it in the async task?

This is my async task code:

```
package async;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import common.Common;
import common.FishCategory;
import http.Network;
import interfaces.ImageDownloader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

public class Async_getAllFishPics extends AsyncTask<FishCategory, Void, FishCategory> {

    String link;
    ImageDownloader callerContext;
    List<FishCategory> categoryList;

    public Async_getAllFishPics(ImageDownloader callerContext, List<FishCategory> categoryList) {
        this.callerContext = callerContext;
        this.categoryList = categoryList;

        for (FishCategory fish : categoryList) {
            link = fish.getLink();
            if (!link.equals("")) {
                String imgpath = Common.getImagePath(link);
                File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), imgpath);
                if (!file.exists() && Network.isNetworkAvailable((Context)callerContext)) {
                    execute(fish);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected FishCategory doInBackground(FishCategory... fishes) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Network.DownloadImage((Context) callerContext, link);

        try {
            saveImage(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fishes[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(FishCategory fish) {
        try {
            fish.setLink(link);
            new Async_getAllFishPics(callerContext, categoryList);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

            String imgpath = Common.getImagePath(link);

            File file = new File(path, imgpath);
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

            String abs = file.getAbsolutePath();

            OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);

            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(((Activity)callerContext).getContentResolver(),abs,file.getName(),file.getName());
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are doing something that may take a long amount of time then you should use a `Service` instead which has it's own `Context`. Alternatively, you could check in `finish()` and stop the task there

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use the ApplicationContext instead? At least you will be sure that the context will exist until you close the application.

`context.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: What happens if I try to access the result of `.getApplicationContext()` when the activity is closed?

Comment: @omega I'm not sure what you mean. If you pass the application context as the context of your async task, it won't matter if the activity you used to access the ApplicationContext is closed.

Comment: For example, if there is a global variable in the context activity thats not static, then if the context is closed, what happens if I try to access it? Also I use the context here `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(((Activity)callerContext).getContentResolver(),abs,file.getName(),file.getName());`, what happens then?

Comment: Activity context != Application context. The only way the async task could be killed it's when the Application is closed, not the activity. Either way, you can't access an async task, it is on another thread.